# why std::map<int, float> cant use operator[]: error C2678?

Tags: c++, stl, std

Having:

```
std::map<const int, float> m_areaCost;
```

I'm trying to compile the following:

```
inline float getAreaCost(const int i) const { 
    return m_areaCost[i]; 
}
```

Which leads to the following error:

```
error C2678: binary '[' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::map<_Kty,_Ty>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

I used to think when we call `[elementId]` we get element value or default element value so I wonder how can such simple case lead to compilation errors?

Comment: While `m_areaCost[i] = cost;` compiles ok...=(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presumably `m_areaCost` is a member of the object that `getAreaCost` is a member of. However, `getAreaCost` is marked as a `const` member function. This means it can't cause any modification to members. So the `m_areaCost` member is `const` in this function.

You cannot call `operator[]` on a `const std::map` because its effect is that it inserts a new element if it does not yet exist. Instead use [`std::map::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at):

```
return m_areaCost.at(i);
```

Comment: I define map not as const - simle class member.

Comment: @DuckQueen But you access it from a `const` method, so you can only call its `const` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Because you state that your function is const, and the [] is not a const operator.
As you said so yourself, the [] !creates or returns a new value.. if it cannot create then you cannot use this operator.. I would use find() and then return the .second value if it is there, something like:

```
auto it = m_areaCost.find(i);
if (it != m_areaCost.end()) return (*it).second
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you marked the method to be `const`.

When you do `return m_areaCost[i];` you can actually create the entry in the map if the key does not exist, therefore the operation is not constant so you have a mismatch between your constant function and non-constant `operator[]` of the map.

If you want the member function to be `const` then you have to use [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) to find the entry for the key.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `getAreaCost` being declared as `const`, like others has stated, but I'd like to give some more suggestions:

A function should always return a useful value, so I would suggest `getAreaCost` to be:

```
inline float getAreaCost(int i) const { 
    std::map<const int, float>::const_iterator It = m_areaCost.find(i);

    if (It != m_areaCost.end()) return It->second;

    return 0.0f;
}
```

Some points:
1. input parameter is pass-by-value, so no need for`const int i`, just use `int i`.
2. if you find things like `std::map<const int, float>::const_iterator` is verbose, give it a `typedef`. (If you dont, feel free to keep write it, of course :P)
3. `0.0f` is just for example, you can return any default value that is suitable in your case.